# Merging more than three similar tables in pandas results in overfolding of column names

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm trying to merge 5 similar tables where each one has the same set of column names, but for 5 different years. The end goal is a table with 21 columns (4 columns x 5 tables, +1 for the name column) and however many rows that match for an inner merge.

To accommodate this, similar column names are usually renamed with postfixes like '_y', '_x', etc. to differentiate them in the new merged table.

But in my case the names from the columns 3rd and 4th tables are being given the same postfixes as the 1st and 2nd tables (the 5th one seems to have no postfixes, ie the original column names). This has resulted in some exact column names in the merged table, which complicates pandas operations downstream. Why is that? I'm wondering why the .merge function is behaving that way. I know I can preserve the desired format by relabeling the original dfs before merging, but I'm curious why the function is displaying the above behavior*.

Here is replicable data:
https://pastebin.com/WEjqmKyz

And the operations I'm using to merge the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import functools

df_list = [df1, df1, df3, df4, df5]

end_df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='name'), df_list)
```

This results in the correct df, except for the naming issue**:

[image]

When I print out the resulting dfs column names, I get the following:

```
 ['name',
 'attacking_crossing_x',
 'skill_dribbling_x',
 'defending_standing_tackle_x',
 'valuation_x',
 'attacking_crossing_y',
 'skill_dribbling_y',
 'defending_standing_tackle_y',
 'valuation_y',
 'attacking_crossing_x',
 'skill_dribbling_x',
 'defending_standing_tackle_x',
 'valuation_x',
 'attacking_crossing_y',
 'skill_dribbling_y',
 'defending_standing_tackle_y',
 'valuation_y',
 'attacking_crossing',
 'skill_dribbling',
 'defending_standing_tackle',
 'valuation']
```

*edit 1
**edit 2

Comment: Are you trying to merge them into 1 dataset with original columns and all data?  If so, did you try an "outer" join?  And then you could groupby name?

Comment: @JeffH, Yes, but I don't think those would address the problem. I did go ahead and try them just in case I'm missing something but it doesn't not change how the column names are treated.

Comment: You just want to merge the five data frames into a single data frame, right? Like if each individual data frame has 5 columns and 4 records, and there are 5 such data frames (in your case) then the resulting data frame will have 5 columns and 20 record, is that correct?

Comment: @vatsalgosar, It would actually be 21 columns (4 columns x 5 tables, +1 for the name column) and however many rows that match for an inner merge. This is because each table represents a year and each row a player. The idea is to track the progress of the player over time. That was unclear in my original question, so I'll clarify it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the info in your comments regarding years, you should:

- add the year to each data frame to preserve info
- merge or concatenate them

That should work like this:

```
In [47]: df1                                                                                                       
Out[47]: 
              name  attacking_crossing  skill_dribbling  defending_standing_tackle  valuation
0     Lionel Messi                -4.0              0.0                        2.0       0.00
1      Luis Suárez                 0.0             -2.0                        0.0      23.56
2           Neymar                 0.0              0.0                        0.0      24.70
3  Sergio Busquets                 0.0              0.0                        2.0       0.95

In [48]: df2                                                                                                       
Out[48]: 
              name  attacking_crossing  skill_dribbling  defending_standing_tackle  valuation
0     Lionel Messi                -3.0              1.0                        5.0        0.0
1      Luis Suárez                 0.0             -2.0                        0.0       15.2
2           Neymar                 4.0              2.0                        0.0       15.2
3  Sergio Busquets                 0.0              0.0                        0.0       15.2

In [49]: dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]                                                                           

In [50]: years = [1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994]                                                                    

In [51]: for year, frame in zip(years, dfs): 
    ...:     frame['year'] = year 
    ...:                                                                                                           

In [52]: df1                                                                                                       
Out[52]: 
              name  attacking_crossing  skill_dribbling  defending_standing_tackle  valuation  year
0     Lionel Messi                -4.0              0.0                        2.0       0.00  1990
1      Luis Suárez                 0.0             -2.0                        0.0      23.56  1990
2           Neymar                 0.0              0.0                        0.0      24.70  1990
3  Sergio Busquets                 0.0              0.0                        2.0       0.95  1990

In [53]: df2                                                                                                       
Out[53]: 
              name  attacking_crossing  skill_dribbling  defending_standing_tackle  valuation  year
0     Lionel Messi                -3.0              1.0                        5.0        0.0  1991
1      Luis Suárez                 0.0             -2.0                        0.0       15.2  1991
2           Neymar                 4.0              2.0                        0.0       15.2  1991
3  Sergio Busquets                 0.0              0.0                        0.0       15.2  1991

In [54]: df_all = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)                                                                

In [55]: df_all                                                                                                    
Out[55]: 
                name  attacking_crossing  skill_dribbling  defending_standing_tackle  valuation  year
0       Lionel Messi                -4.0              0.0                        2.0      0.000  1990
1        Luis Suárez                 0.0             -2.0                        0.0     23.560  1990
2             Neymar                 0.0              0.0                        0.0     24.700  1990
3    Sergio Busquets                 0.0              0.0                        2.0      0.950  1990
4       Lionel Messi                -3.0              1.0                        5.0      0.000  1991
5        Luis Suárez                 0.0             -2.0                        0.0     15.200  1991
6             Neymar                 4.0              2.0                        0.0     15.200  1991
7    Sergio Busquets                 0.0              0.0                        0.0     15.200  1991
8       Lionel Messi                 0.0              0.0                        0.0      0.000  1992
9             Neymar                 0.0              0.0                        0.0     19.000  1992
10       Luis Suárez                 0.0              0.0                        0.0      0.000  1992
11       Luka Modric                 0.0              0.0                        0.0     -8.550  1992
12      Lionel Messi                 0.0              0.0                        0.0     60.800  1993
13       Luis Suárez                 0.0              1.0                        0.0    -20.900  1993
14            Neymar                 4.0              0.0                        0.0     72.200  1993
15       Gareth Bale                 0.0             -2.0                        0.0     -7.125  1993
16      Lionel Messi                11.0              0.0                        9.0    -26.600  1994
17       Luis Suárez                 1.0             -2.0                        0.0    -24.700  1994
18            Neymar                 2.0              2.0                        0.0     52.440  1994
19  Leonardo Bonucci                 0.0              0.0                        0.0     -7.980  1994
```

Comment: Ok.  I can't imagine an application where that would be preferable with all the goofy appended column names that you would need to keep track of.  The above is a pretty universal "flat" format.  What is it you are trying to do with the data that you want all of the columns?

Comment: It looks like for charting, stacking is the best course of action, so you are correct. Thanks for the help